# Python scrapy script - AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'urljoin'

Tags: python, dictionary, scrapy

The following is an execution of scrapy to populate dynamodb with urls as a result of the scrape. I am getting the error:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'urljoin'

however, and am unclear why.

```
##############################################
#  Script:  Prep storage for chemtrail       #
#  Author: James                             #
#  Purpose:                                  #
#  Version:                                  #
#                                            #
##############################################
import boto3
import json
import scrapy

class ChemPrepSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "xxxxxx"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.xxxxxxx.com.au'
        ]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self,response):
        dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
        table = dynamodb.Table('chemTrailStorage')
        category_links = response.css('li').xpath('a/@href').getall()
        category_links_filtered = [x for x in category_links if 'shop-online' in x] # remove non category links
        category_links_filtered = list(dict.fromkeys(category_links_filtered)) # remove duplicates 

        for category_link in category_links_filtered:
            print('raw category -> ' + category_link)
            next_category = response.urljoin(category_link) + '?size=99999'
            print('DynamoDb insert for category: ' + next_category)
            response = table.put_item(
                Item={
                    'CategoryPath': next_category,
                    'ItemCount':"99999",
                    'JobStat':"NOT_STARTED",
                    'PickupDateTime':"NA",
                    'CompletionDateTime':"NA"
                }
            )
            print('Response from put....')
            print(response)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like boto3 return a "Dict" from the table.put_item command - see here in AWS boto3 [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.query).

This means you are overriding the Scrapy "response" object with a "Dict" - which doesn't have the urljoin attribute.

You should just replace "response = table.put_item" with dynamo_response = table.put_item

Or some other name of your choice.